# Counting Number Of Selected Checkbox & Checking all

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Im bringing values from my Database.As you know,sometimes you want to check multiple rows to delete or update.And you would like to know how much did you selected.

What I need is:

-- Number of selected checkboxes
-- Checking all checkboxes using one checkbox

Here is how I can loop multiple checkbox es without any function:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
  echo '<table id="registrations_table_results" border=1  align=center >
  <thead style="font-weight:bold;">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkall"></td>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name Surname</td>
        <td>Unique ID</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>';    

    $adsoyad = $_POST['adsoyad'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from kullanicilar where adsoyad like '%$adsoyad%'");


    while ($read = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {       
        $id = $read['ID'];
        $adsoyad = $read['adsoyad'];
        $tc = $read['tc'];

        echo '
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="check"></td>
                <td>'.$id.'</td>
                <td>'.$adsoyad.'</td>
                <td>'.$tc.'</td>
            </tr>
            ';
    }
  }
```

Here how looks like:

[image: problem]
At this point as you can see,there are checkbox es near each result when clicked the search button.And 1 at the table header to check all.I have tried multiple of functions there but they seemed to not work.I decided to copy-paste the work of mine here ,So it would be better to fit the function I needed here.

**EDIT:Those checkboxes were not created by hand manually.But it does as much as numbers of rows.**

Comment: Can you please help me by incuding that in my work?

Comment: Consider using JavaScript, it would be more suited for this sort of feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a sample code with check all, and check count on checkbox change in jQuery
see the code below: It also gets the output of an uncheck checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Checkbox check event
        $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function(){
               //update count every check change event
               //total of all check[] checked
               var checkedcount = $("input[name='check[]']:checked").length;
           console.log("Total checked items" + checkedcount);
          //Check values of all check[]
          setTimeout(function(){
          var checkboxes = $("input[name='check[]']");
          $.each(checkboxes , function(index, element){
                //check if the current checkbox is checked
                var ischecked = $(checkboxes[index]).is(":checked") ? true : false;
                 //sample output
                 console.log(index + " value=" + element.value + " / ischecked? =" + ischecked);
             });
          });

        });
  
        $("input[name='checkall']").on("change", function(){
            if ( $("input[name='checkall']:checked" ) ) {
             $("input[name='check[]']").not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            }
        }).trigger("onchange");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkall"> Check all</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="number one">1</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="number two">2</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="number three">3</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="number four">4</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="number five">5</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

First you need to rename your checkbox to something like below:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
```

On **Submit** you could do :

```
$checkboxes = $_POST['check'];
$cbCount = count($checkboxes);
```

To check each checkboxes values in php

```
foreach($checkboxes as $checkbox) {
   // some code here

}
```

count checked items in `jQuery` on check change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='check[]']").on("change", function(){
           //update count every check change event
           var count = $("input[name='check[]']:checked").length;
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesnt know where 'check' comes from with 'Undefined variable "  check".I guess you are missing the point.Those checkbox es are not created by hand manually.It does echo as much as rows of results.Plus,It should work like "CheckedChange" event .

Comment: I posted the code so you could count it using php, you should clarify your question and indicate that you need to implement the checks using a checkedchange event which isn't available on php. The code I provided you will cout all the checkboxes even if created dynamically or no matter how many it is since it will be in array when submitted.

Comment: I updated the answer and added how to check on change and captures checkboxes value checked or uncheck. see the updated answer

Comment: The problem was,When I tried to load those jS functions from a seperate file,It didnt work.But when I put whole code on the top of the page between <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags,It worked.I really appreciate your effort and thank you for this great share.It checks when I want it all to be checked.But only one thing to go,I cant get the number of checked checkboxes.